# Discarding specific html elements in Solr crawling using Tika-parser library

Tags: solr, apache-tika, html-parser

I am crawling the website using the Solr post tool. I am able to mention the HTML elements content need to be indexed in Solr using SAFE_ELEMENTS and SAFE_ATTRIBUTES of org.apache.tika.parser.html.DefaultHtmlMapper I want all the h1 and p elements present on a page. But I want to exclude h1 and p elements content if they are present inside header and footer tags. Because that is common to all the pages of a site.

There is something called DISCARDABLE_ELEMENTS in org.apache.tika.parser.html.DefaultHtmlMapper. I have added header and footer in the DISCARDABLE_ELEMENTS. Still, I am getting the contents of h1 and p present inside header and footer tags.

```
    private static final Set<String> DISCARDABLE_ELEMENTS = new HashSet<String>() {{
        add("STYLE");
        add("SCRIPT");
        add("HEADER");
        add("FOOTER");
        add("NAV");
    }};
```

I have created a new class which implements HtmlMapper.

```
public class RemoveAttributeHtmlMapper implements HtmlMapper {

    // Based on http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd
    private static final Map<String, String> SAFE_ELEMENTS = new HashMap<String, String>() {{
        put("H1", "h1");
        put("H2", "h2");
//        put("H3", "h3");
//        put("H4", "h4");
//        put("H5", "h5");
//        put("H6", "h6");

        put("P", "p");
        put("PRE", "pre");
        put("BLOCKQUOTE", "blockquote");
        put("Q", "q");

        put("UL", "ul");
        put("OL", "ol");
        put("MENU", "ul");
        put("LI", "li");
        put("DL", "dl");
        put("DT", "dt");
        put("DD", "dd");

        put("TABLE", "table");
        put("THEAD", "thead");
        put("TBODY", "tbody");
        put("TR", "tr");
        put("TH", "th");
        put("TD", "td");

        put("ADDRESS", "address");

        // TIKA-460 - add anchors
        put("A", "a");  

        // TIKA-463 - add additional elements that contain URLs (and their sub-elements)
        put("MAP", "map");
        put("AREA", "area");
        put("IMG", "img");
        put("FRAMESET", "frameset");
        put("FRAME", "frame");
        put("IFRAME", "iframe");
        put("OBJECT", "object");
        put("PARAM", "param");
        put("INS", "ins");
        put("DEL", "del");

    }};

    private static final Set<String> DISCARDABLE_ELEMENTS = new HashSet<String>() {{
        add("STYLE");
        add("SCRIPT");
        add("HEADER");
        add("FOOTER");
        add("NAV");
       // add("HEAD");
    }};

    // For information on tags & attributes, see:
    // http://www.w3.org/TR/2002/REC-xhtml1-20020801/dtds.html#a_dtd_XHTML-1.0-Strict
    // http://www.w3schools.com/TAGS/
    private static final Map<String, Set<String>> SAFE_ATTRIBUTES = new HashMap<String, Set<String>>() {{

//      put("a", attrSet(""));
      put("a", attrSet("charset", "type", "name", "href", "hreflang", "rel", "rev", "shape", "coords"));
      put("img", attrSet(""));
      put("frame", attrSet(""));
      put("iframe",attrSet(""));
      put("link", attrSet(""));
      put("map", attrSet(""));
      put("area", attrSet(""));
      put("object", attrSet(""));
      put("param", attrSet(""));
      put("blockquote", attrSet(""));
      put("ins", attrSet(""));
      put("del", attrSet(""));
      put("q", attrSet(""));

        put("h1", attrSet(""));
        put("h2", attrSet(""));
        put("p", attrSet(""));
        // TODO - fill out this set. Include core, i18n, etc sets where appropriate.
    }};

    private static Set<String> attrSet(String... attrs) {
        Set<String> result = new HashSet<String>();
        for (String attr : attrs) {
            result.add(attr);
        }
        return result;
    }

    /**
     * @since Apache Tika 0.8
     */
    public static final HtmlMapper INSTANCE = new RemoveAttributeHtmlMapper();

    public String mapSafeElement(String name) {
        return SAFE_ELEMENTS.get(name);
    }

    /** Normalizes an attribute name. Assumes that the element name 
     * is valid and normalized 
     */
    public String mapSafeAttribute(String elementName, String attributeName) {
        Set<String> safeAttrs = SAFE_ATTRIBUTES.get(elementName);
        if ((safeAttrs != null) && safeAttrs.contains(attributeName)) {
            return attributeName;
        } else {
            return null;
        }
    }

    public boolean isDiscardElement(String name) {
        return DISCARDABLE_ELEMENTS.contains(name);
    }

}
```

Any help in this would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: How have you added these elements? What's the code? How are you using Tika?

Comment: @MatsLindh I have added my full code.

Comment: Have you made sure that your mapper is actually running (i.e. does it get invoked at all?)? Does your mapper return the content you expect it to do (in particular, outside of Solr)?

Answer (score 0):

I have resolved the issue. Solr uses tagsoup library to parse the HTML elements. By default tagsoup 1.2 doesn't support HTML5 elemnts like header, footer etc.. They provide a patch code to resolve the issue.
[Issue Link](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/TIKA-985) and the [patch code Link](https://issues.apache.org/jira/secure/attachment/12543079/TIKA-985-1.3-2.patch)

Here they guided to use tagsoup 1.3.2. I replaced the default tagsoup 1.2 from solr. After, When I tried to run the crawl, it throws an error. When I tried the same patch code with default tagsoup 1.2, it works. You have to add the patch code in tika-parsers-1.7.jar. For this download the tika project from [Github](https://github.com/apache/tika), add the patch code in the tika-parsers/src/main/java/org/apache/tika/parser/html/HtmlParser.java file, compile it to the jar using maven and upload it to Solr.